# How to include negative values STAR plotting

Tags: r

I am using this function called "[star](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/stars.html)" to plot my values ranging from negative to positive values.
By default the scale is from 0 to 1. Is it possible to include the negative values while plotting?

My data:

```
                 X1 X2 X3
AP         1405.706720        225.51701          -262.66689
PP           -286.345142        193.28586          422.23567
```

Comment: how should those be plotted? In the opposite direction??

Comment: FYI the thing you linked to is a function, not a package. There is a package called [STAR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/STAR/STAR.pdf), but it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the function you linked to.

Comment: sorry not package just function. Yes may be in opposite direction.How can I do that ?

Comment: As noted in the help page, you might find it easier to use `symbols` .